# Prevent Dualshock 4 from pretending to be a mouse?

Tags: touchpad, steam, gamepad

All it says in the header: I can't stand the touchpad, it works all the time. I'd like to just stop behaving as a mouse in Linux environment, but keep the touchpad in case to remap controls in Steam games (meaning not completely shut down the touchpad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off touchpad in Ubuntu settings was my solution...